# Error when attempting to parse xhr response text For Long Size File

Tags: jquery, asp.net, file, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using the Jquery fineUploader for Upload the file I am getting

**404 - File or directory not found.**

when uploading the file more than 30MB for Small files below than 30MB works fine.

In fire bug the error shows:

```
[FineUploader] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text
(SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character)

 [FineUploader] Caught exception in 'onValidate' callback -TypeError: file is undefined
 log(a="[FineUploader] Caught e...rror: file is undefined", b="error")
```

[image]

below is my handler code:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string directoryID = context.Request["dId"];
    var response = new AjaxResponse { ResponseData = "" };

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(directoryID))
    {
        int spaceID = 0;
        int dirID = Convert.ToInt32(directoryID);

        string directoryPhysicalPath = "D:\\Files\\";
        string fileName = context.Request["qqfile"];

        string saveLocation = Path.Combine(directoryPhysicalPath, fileUniqueName);
        if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPhysicalPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPhysicalPath);
        }

        DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;

        var file = new File();
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            Stream inputStream = context.Request.InputStream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.Length];

            try
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(saveLocation, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    do
                    {
                        bytesRead = context.Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    } while (bytesRead > 0);
                }

                file = new File
                {
                    FileName = fileName
                };

               //Add to DB Here

            }
        }
        catch (PathTooLongException ex)
        {
            response.IsError = true;
            response.ResponseMessage = ex.Message;
        }

        File f = //Get data from DB here;

        response.ResponseData = f;

        context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(response));

    }
}
```

Comment: One error is in your server side code.  Show your server side code so we can assist.  Also show your client side code so we can make more sense of the onvalidate error.

Comment: All are working on my local machine gives error only on Server.

Comment: It appears that you are attempting to serialize a File type into a JSON object. I'm not sure how .NET internally stores objects of type `File` (or is it a class instance? Oh .Net, it's been a while). Usually, you need to serialize some sort of hash-map into JSON. Also, Fine Uploader expects the response to have a property of `success` with a value of `true`.

Comment: You'll need to post your client-side code as well, as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Thanks,
I have solve this issue to put the below settings in web.config under `<system.webServer>` section

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering >
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000"/>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```